# jQuery - Close Dialog When Clicked Outside

Tags: javascript, jquery

Every-time a user clicks on Register or Login link, a popup window appears to proceed. But the user is supposed to click the Login or register link again if he wants to close the popup window. Is it possible to close the popup window if click is made anywhere else on the webpage?

This is the code for Dropdown menu on my webpage:

```
<!---dropdown--->
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    function showlogin(){
        $("#loginbox").animate({"height": "toggle"}, { duration: 800 });
        $("#regsiterbox").hide();
        $(".login a").css("color", "#bf1e1a");
        $(".create-account a").css("color", "#747474");
    }
    function showregister(){
        $("#regsiterbox").animate({"height": "toggle"}, { duration: 800 });
        $("#loginbox").hide();
        $(".create-account a").css("color", "#bf1e1a");
        $(".login a").css("color", "#747474");
    }
    //]]>
</script>
<!---dropdown--->
```

Any help would be appreciated !

Comment: Can you show the problem in jsfiddle.net ?

Comment: Please clarify what "anywhere else" is ? Else than what ? Is that outside of the popup window?

Comment: Yes, I mean outside the popup window.

Comment: may you consider to use **mouseleave** from dropdown instead click ouside.

Answer (score 1):

Add a class .modal to every popup box you have on the page and add the following. It will hide any popup box with a class .modal when clicked.

```
$('body').on('click',function(){
     if(!$(this).hasClass('modal')){
        $(".modal").hide();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$('body').on('click',function(){
     if($("#regsiterbox").css('display') != "none"){
           $("#regsiterbox").hide();
     }
     else if($("#loginbox").css('display') != "none"){
          $("#loginbox").hide();
     }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can identify your popup by a class, i chose `popup` here. 
This code will hide the `popup` class element whenever a click is made outside of it. 
So clicks on the window will not close it.

```
$("body").click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("class") != "popup") {
       $(".popup").hide();
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('body').on('click',function(event){
  event.stopPropagation();     
  $(".your_popup").hide();
});
```